# Laravel 5.4 session doesn't seem to persist after Auth::login

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Despite many people with this problem, the solutions I've found are not working. I'm just trying to use Augh::login($user) and then redirect. I've verified immediately after calling login() that the user is being logged in, however, once I redirect, I get bounced back to the login scree. Here are my routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'admin\adminRootController@dashboard')->middleware('auth');
});
```

I've spent about 5 hours on different solutions to absolutely no end, someone please help!!!!!!!

Comment: Use multiple tags so your question gets noticed and reaches more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your routes to this:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'admin\adminRootController@dashboard')
});
```

`Auth::routes()` need not be placed in any route groups as it is configured by the framework already. If you want to protect any routes, make sure to use `auth` middleware in your routes.